# use sed to remove header from 'virsh list' output

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

I'm working on a script that will only shutdown my server once all the VMs are powered off.  The most reliable way I've found to do this is with:
  `ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list'`

which will give me something like this:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     DNSserver                      running
 3     salt                           running
 4     logserver                      running
 5     webserver                      running
 6     mail                           running
 7     fileserver                     running
```

When all the VMs are shutdown, it will simply show:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

So I'm looking for a way to get my bash script to wait till the list is empty and then issue the shutdown command to the server.  I don't want to rely on `expect` as not all systems have that command.  Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# stuff to shutdown VMs here (snipped) #
output=$(ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list')
# need something here to strip out the header
[ "$output" == "" ] && shutdown -h now
```

I've tried using variations on both `grep` and `sed` but I get errors about the dashes.  For example:

```
$ sed -i "Id Name State ----------------------------------------------------" $output
sed: unrecognized option '----------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: If you want to remove the first 2 lines of a file with `sed` then e.g.: `sed '1,2d' file`

Comment: Right, but I'm not processing a file.  I'm processing a string stored in a variable.

Comment: Just count lines: `[ "$(ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list' | wc -l)" -le 2 ] && shutdown -h now`

Comment: Replace "# need something here to strip out the header" with: `output="$(echo "$output" | sed  '1,2d')`

Comment: As @MarkYoung pointed out in his answer, there is a certain danger to just pulling the first two lines.  I'd rather pull out the expected output than just hope that the first two lines matched correctly.  This is still a better option than my current implementation using `ping` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep for lines that are 0 or more spaces and a number, if not empty, shutdown:

`[ -n "$(ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list' |  grep -E '^\s*\d+')" ] && shutdown -h`

grep for lines that are 0 or more spaces and a number, if 1 or more lines match, shutdown:

`[ "$(ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list' |  grep -E '^\s*\d+' | wc -l)" -ge 1 ] && shutdown -h`

remove the first two lines of the output and count them. if lines exist, shutdown.
*i personally consider this unsafe as it's unpredictable. there is no way to know what those first two lines were*
`[ "$(ssh root@vmserver 'virsh list' | sed '1,2d' | wc -l)" -ge 1 ] && shutdown -h`

Comment: That's why I was originally looking for a way to remove the *expected* output and then base the shutdown logic on whether there was anything left.  However all the dashes were confusing both `sed` and `grep` as I documented in my question.

Answer (score 4):

I use just ...

```
for VM in $(virsh list --state-running --name); do echo "shotdown $VM"; done
```

... in bash shell script to shutdown all my vms.
Where the "echo" is, you can put your shutdown code!

Comment: `for vm in $(virsh list --all --name); do virsh domstate $vm; done` gets just the status